# Errors when trying to setup app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app to Heroku. I've installed the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) but when I try to login on my mac I get the following errors. How can I fix this?

I'm on rails 3.2.0 and ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]

```
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/excon-0.15.4/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:84: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0023 p:---- s:0115 b:0115 l:000114 d:000114 CFUNC  :connect
c:0022 p:0650 s:0112 b:0112 l:000111 d:000111 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/excon-0.15.4/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:84
c:0021 p:---- s:0102 b:0102 l:000101 d:000101 FINISH
c:0020 p:---- s:0100 b:0100 l:000099 d:000099 CFUNC  :new
c:0019 p:0064 s:0095 b:0092 l:000091 d:000091 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/excon-0.15.4/lib/excon/connection.rb:348
c:0018 p:0036 s:0089 b:0089 l:000088 d:000088 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/excon-0.15.4/lib/excon/connection.rb:179
c:0017 p:0366 s:0080 b:0080 l:000079 d:000079 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/excon-0.15.4/lib/excon/connection.rb:105
c:0016 p:0019 s:0071 b:0071 l:000070 d:000070 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api.rb:60
c:0015 p:0037 s:0062 b:0062 l:000061 d:000061 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/login.rb:9
c:0014 p:0080 s:0057 b:0057 l:000056 d:000056 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb:76
c:0013 p:0093 s:0051 b:0050 l:000049 d:000049 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb:185
c:0012 p:0025 s:0045 b:0045 l:000044 d:000044 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb:217
c:0011 p:0038 s:0041 b:0041 l:000040 d:000040 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb:80
c:0010 p:0021 s:0038 b:0038 l:000037 d:000037 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb:41
c:0009 p:0029 s:0035 b:0035 l:000034 d:000034 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/auth.rb:22
c:0008 p:0046 s:0032 b:0032 l:000031 d:000031 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command.rb:179
c:0007 p:0112 s:0022 b:0022 l:000021 d:000021 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/cli.rb:25
c:0006 p:0133 s:0016 b:0016 l:000015 d:000015 TOP    /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/bin/heroku:16
c:0005 p:---- s:0013 b:0013 l:000012 d:000012 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0011 b:0011 l:000010 d:000010 CFUNC  :load
c:0003 p:0127 s:0007 b:0007 l:002048 d:000330 EVAL   /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/heroku:19
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:002048 d:002048 TOP   

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/bin/heroku:16:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/cli.rb:25:in `start'
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command.rb:179:in `run'
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/auth.rb:22:in `login'
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb:41:in `login'
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb:80:in `get_credentials'
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb:217:in `ask_for_and_save_credentials'
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb:185:in `ask_for_credentials'
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb:76:in `api_key'
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/login.rb:9:in `post_login'
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api.rb:60:in `request'
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/excon-0.15.4/lib/excon/connection.rb:105:in `request'
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/excon-0.15.4/lib/excon/connection.rb:179:in `request_kernel'
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/excon-0.15.4/lib/excon/connection.rb:348:in `socket'
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/excon-0.15.4/lib/excon/connection.rb:348:in `new'
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/excon-0.15.4/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:84:in `initialize'
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/excon-0.15.4/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:84:in `connect'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

   See Crash Report log file under ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter or
   /Library/Logs/CrashReporter, for the more detail of.

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/heroku

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/enc/encdb.bundle
    2 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
    3 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb
    4 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/rbconfig.rb
    5 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    6 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb
    7 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb
    8 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb
    9 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/version.rb
   10 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb
   11 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb
   12 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/platform.rb
   13 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb
   14 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/path_support.rb
   15 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/pathname.bundle
   16 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/pathname.rb
   17 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/stringio.bundle
   18 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/vendor/heroku/okjson.rb
   19 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/helpers.rb
   20 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/updater.rb
   21 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parseexception.rb
   22 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/formatters/default.rb
   23 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/formatters/pretty.rb
   24 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/node.rb
   25 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/child.rb
   26 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parent.rb
   27 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/xmltokens.rb
   28 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/namespace.rb
   29 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/encoding.rb
   30 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/source.rb
   31 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/entity.rb
   32 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/attlistdecl.rb
   33 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/doctype.rb
   34 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/text.rb
   35 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/attribute.rb
   36 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/cdata.rb
   37 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/functions.rb
   38 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/syncenumerator.rb
   39 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parsers/xpathparser.rb
   40 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/xpath_parser.rb
   41 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/xpath.rb
   42 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/element.rb
   43 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/xmldecl.rb
   44 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/comment.rb
   45 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/instruction.rb
   46 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/rexml.rb
   47 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/output.rb
   48 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/undefinednamespaceexception.rb
   49 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/set.rb
   50 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parsers/baseparser.rb
   51 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parsers/streamparser.rb
   52 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/validation/validationexception.rb
   53 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parsers/treeparser.rb
   54 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/document.rb
   55 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb
   56 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb
   57 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ftp.rb
   58 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/http.rb
   59 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/https.rb
   60 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ldap.rb
   61 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ldaps.rb
   62 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/mailto.rb
   63 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri.rb
   64 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/date_core.bundle
   65 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date/format.rb
   66 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date.rb
   67 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/time.rb
   68 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/core.rb
   69 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/cookie.rb
   70 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/util.rb
   71 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi.rb
   72 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/netrc-0.7.5/lib/netrc.rb
   73 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb
   74 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/plugin.rb
   75 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/builtin_plugin.rb
   76 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/version.rb
   77 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb
   78 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command.rb
   79 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/client/ssl_endpoint.rb
   80 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/client.rb
   81 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku.rb
   82 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/cli.rb
   83 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/etc.bundle
   84 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb
   85 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb
   86 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/socket.bundle
   87 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/socket.rb
   88 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb
   89 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/base.rb
   90 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/account.rb
   91 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/accounts.rb
   92 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/helpers/heroku_postgresql.rb
   93 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/addons.rb
   94 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/apps.rb
   95 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/auth.rb
   96 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/certs.rb
   97 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/config.rb
   98 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/db.rb
   99 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/domains.rb
  100 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/drains.rb
  101 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/git.rb
  102 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/deprecated.rb
  103 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/deprecated/help.rb
  104 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/help.rb
  105 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/keys.rb
  106 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/labs.rb
  107 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/logs.rb
  108 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/maintenance.rb
  109 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/digest.bundle
  110 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/digest.rb
  111 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/digest/sha2.bundle
  112 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/digest/sha2.rb
  113 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/client/heroku_postgresql.rb
  114 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb
  115 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/client/pgbackups.rb
  116 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/pgbackups.rb
  117 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/plugins.rb
  118 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/ps.rb
  119 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/releases.rb
  120 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/readline.bundle
  121 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/run.rb
  122 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/sharing.rb
  123 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/ssl.rb
  124 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/stack.rb
  125 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/status.rb
  126 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/update.rb
  127 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-2.30.1/lib/heroku/command/version.rb
  128 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/base64.rb
  129 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb
  130 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/openssl.bundle
  131 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/bn.rb
  132 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/cipher.rb
  133 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/config.rb
  134 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/digest.rb
  135 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb
  136 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/fcntl.bundle
  137 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/ssl-internal.rb
  138 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/x509-internal.rb
  139 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl.rb
  140 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/excon-0.15.4/lib/excon/constants.rb
  141 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/excon-0.15.4/lib/excon/connection.rb
  142 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/excon-0.15.4/lib/excon/errors.rb
  143 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/excon-0.15.4/lib/excon/response.rb
  144 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/excon-0.15.4/lib/excon/socket.rb
  145 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/excon-0.15.4/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb
  146 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/excon-0.15.4/lib/excon/standard_instrumentor.rb
  147 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/excon-0.15.4/lib/excon.rb
  148 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/securerandom.rb
  149 /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/zlib.bundle
  150 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/vendor/okjson.rb
  151 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/errors.rb
  152 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/mock/addons.rb
  153 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/mock/apps.rb
  154 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/mock/collaborators.rb
  155 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/mock/config_vars.rb
  156 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/mock/domains.rb
  157 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/mock/features.rb
  158 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/mock/keys.rb
  159 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/mock/login.rb
  160 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/mock/logs.rb
  161 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/mock/processes.rb
  162 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/mock/releases.rb
  163 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/mock/stacks.rb
  164 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/mock/user.rb
  165 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/mock.rb
  166 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/version.rb
  167 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/addons.rb
  168 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/apps.rb
  169 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/collaborators.rb
  170 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/config_vars.rb
  171 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/domains.rb
  172 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/features.rb
  173 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/keys.rb
  174 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/login.rb
  175 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/logs.rb
  176 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/processes.rb
  177 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/releases.rb
  178 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/stacks.rb
  179 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api/user.rb
  180 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api.rb
  181 /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku-api.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do 2 things

- heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
- $gem uninstall heroku

After I did that it worked